# Fingerprint doesn't work in linux (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS)

Tags: linux, drivers, devices, pop-os, fingerprint

I am trying to enable fingerprint, but when I run `sudo fprintd-enroll` it shows this `Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`.
can anyone help me?
LENOVO IDEAPAD FLEX 5I